# What is the difference between connection string and StorageCredentials for accessing Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-security, defaultazurecredential

I'm looking into using Azure Blob Storage and, from looking at several tutorials, I get that one can access the blob storage through a connection string or using StorageCredentials.

Is there a best practice? Or do both serve a different purpose?

Cheers, B.

Answer (score -1):

Both StorageCredentials and connection string are used to connect to Storage Account using Azure SDKs.

Both StorageCredentials and connection string serve the same purpose.

StorageCredentials class supports both **SAS token** and **account name, account key**

Even the connection string supports both **SAS Token** and **account name, account key**

For more information about StorageCredentials, please refer: [StorageCredentials Class (Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.auth.storagecredentials?view=azure-dotnet)

For more information about Connection String, please refer: [Configure a connection string - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)